# How to create Azure DigitalTwin models,relationships and twins using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, model, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment, azure-digital-twins

Is there a way to deploy the Azure Digital twin **models,relationships and twins** using ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, creating models, twins, and relationships is considered a 'data plane' operation and is not available via ARM.  You need to use SDKs, AZ CLI, or REST.

However, you can do those things via a "post deployment script" from an ARM deployment.  For an example of how do that, see this deployment which has an ARM template that deploys the ADT instance (among other things) and then pre-creates a twin graph via a bash post-deployment script (despite it ending in .ps1, which is an error).

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/digital-twins-samples/tree/master/HandsOnLab/deployment

Answer (score 0):

No, ARM templates are used to deploy infrastructure.

Azure Digital Twin models are deployed through SDKs, az cli commands and REST API calls.